# Running SQL Server queries against sqlite or plain files?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a website developed using a SQL Server database. But I need to port it to a new web server that doesn't have access to a database.

I therefore need an alternative solution, preferably without rewriting all the database queries. I would prefer being able to run the same queries against a sqlite file or just a plain textfile.

As far as storage goes it won't be storing large amounts of data, so performance won't be an issue.

Thanks for your time!,

Kind regards

Comment: What about Sql Server Compact Edition?

Comment: What language is your website written in?  There are lots of options for lightweight databases that you can query with SQL.

Comment: typically, any proper server contains a database driver interface that can be satisfyied by any database. it can be memory base, file system base, server-space sql database (such as SQLite can be) or a full fledged database such as PostgreSQL. read you server documentation

Comment: Joel Coehoorn's comment should be converted to answer - SQL Server Compact Edition - compatible queries and no database engine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about using Compact Edition, I didn't even know such a Microsoft product existed. The port was trivial and it's now working great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using Sql Server Compact Edition (see comments in OP).